# Display output from multiple variables in a for loop

Tags: powershell, formatting, export-to-csv

I am trying to output different attributes of a Skype response group queue for documentation purpose.

I want to get `Name`, `TimeoutThreshold`, `TimeoutAction` , `Timeouturi`, `OverflowThreshold`, `OverflowAction` , `OverflowCandidate` as a `.csv` file header in row 1 and then the output to be entered in various columns from row 2.

I have tried below, but the formatting is really bad and the headers keep repeating. Can some one please help.

Also tried getting output in HTML, but no luck.

```
$p = Get-CsRgsQueue | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "IPL*"} | Select-Object Name

foreach ($Name in $p)
{
    $q   = Get-CsRgsQueue -Name "$Name"
    $N   = $q.Name
    $TT  = $q.TimeoutThreshold
    $TA  = $q.TimeoutAction.Action
    $TAU = $q.TimeoutAction.uri
    $OF  = $q.OverflowThreshold
    $OFA = $q.OverflowAction
    $OFC = $q.OverflowCandidate

    $out = New-Object PSObject
    $out | Add-Member NoteProperty QueueName $N
    $out | Add-Member NoteProperty Timeout $TT
    $out | Add-Member NoteProperty TimeoutAction $TA
    $out | Add-Member NoteProperty TransferURI $TAU
    $out | Add-Member NoteProperty OverflowThreshhold $OF
    $out | Add-Member NoteProperty OverflowAction $OFA
    $out | Add-Member NoteProperty OverflowCandidate $OFC

    $out | FT -AutoSize | Export-Csv C:\abc.csv -Append
}
```

Comment: you have to omit ` | FT -AutoSize` in the last line.

Comment: To neaten it up, you can use a hash table for your properties, it is known as splatting. Hopefully the formatting looks ok. EDITED *** Grr, sorry about formatting below.

Comment: foreach ($name in $P)
$properties = @{ $q = get-csrgsqueue -name "$Name" 
                            $N = $q.Name
                            $TT = $q.TimeoutThreshold 
                            $TA = $q.TimeoutAction.Action
                            $TAU= $q.TimeoutAction.uri
                            $OF= $q.OverflowThreshold
                            $OFA= $q.OverflowAction
                            $OFC= $q.OverflowCandidate
                          }
    new-object -TypeName psobject -Property $properties

Comment: Each property should be on a new line if formatting worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried below, but the formatting is really bad and the headers
>   keep repeating. Can some one please help.

That's because you pipe your objects through `FT -AutoSize` (`Format-Table -AutoSize`) - only ever use the `Format-*` cmdlets when you're about to show/present your data.

You can also save some time by only calling `Get-CsRgsQueue` once, piping it to `ForEach-Object` and finally construct a hashtable for the object properties:

```
Get-CsRgsQueue | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "IPL*"} | ForEach-Object {
    New-object psobject -Property @{
        QueueName          = $_.Name
        Timeout            = $_.TimoutThreshold
        TimeoutAction      = $_.TimeoutAction.Action
        TransferURI        = $_.TimeoutAction.Uri
        OverflowThreshhold = $_.OverflowThreshold
        OverflowAction     = $_.OverflowAction
        OverflowCandidate  = $_.OverflowCandicate
    }
} |Export-Csv c:\abc.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score -2):

short solution of Mathias Jessen

```
Get-CsRgsQueue | where Name -like "IPL*" | %{
    [pscustomobject] @{
    QueueName          = $_.Name
    Timeout            = $_.TimoutThreshold
    TimeoutAction      = $_.TimeoutAction.Action
    TransferURI        = $_.TimeoutAction.Uri
    OverflowThreshhold = $_.OverflowThreshold
    OverflowAction     = $_.OverflowAction
    OverflowCandidate  = $_.OverflowCandicate
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\result.csv -NoType
```